# Error with PDO and MySql: Could not find driver even when I enable it in the php.ini

Tags: php, pdo, php-8

I've tried to connect to my database using basic code and error checking but when I try it gives this error :

> Could not find driver"

even when I enable `extension=pdo_mysql`.

By the way, when I do phpInfo(); it says that I'm on 8.0.30 if this can help.

Also, it says that the pdo drivers has novalue. Could it be because of the fact that the client api version is 8.3.4 and not 8.0 like php ?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: There can be multiple `php.ini` files for eg CLI, web, etc. Make sure you're editing the correct `php.ini` file for the environment you're trying to use. Running `phpinfo()` should show you the location

Comment: I'm on linux ubuntu (in Virtual Box) and I know I'm editing the right php.ini file by looking the phpinfo().

Comment: I would suggest to uninstall every php-related package and then install anew, from Sury repo

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have the `pdo_mysql` library installed in your PHP `ext/` folder. If it exists, you may have a typo in your `php.ini` file (you need to uncomment `extension=pdo_mysql`). Otherwise, you might first need to install the appropriate PDO database drivers.

You can try list your extensions using `php -m` to ensure that PHP detects the library.

Comment: It is installed (when I do php -m there is pdo_mysql)

Answer (score -2):

You can also try the following command to ensure library is loaded and enabled.

```
php --ri pdo_mysql

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 8.2.7
```

otherwise:

```
php --ri pdo_mysql
Extension 'pdo_mysql' not present.
```

Comment: The question is not how to ensure. The OP already knows the library is NOT loaded

Comment: It says that it is enabled but that it is unable to load it because of an "undefined symbole: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: is that the whole error message?